# Code works in an HTML page but not in an ASP.NET page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I'm using a `dateplustimepicker` control which works fine on an HTML page but does not work when used on an ASP.NET page. Here's the code I'm using on the ASP.NET page:

```
<div>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

  <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <link href="css/jquery-dateplustimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-dateplustimepicker.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {

          $('#limit-dateplustimepicker').dateplustimepicker({

              minTime: { hours: 8, minutes: 30 },

              maxTime: { hours: 20 }

          });
      });
  </script>


  <input type="text" id="limit-dateplustimepicker" name="limit-dateplustimepicker" />

</div>
```

Why does it work as an HTML page but not as an ASP.NET aspx page?

Comment: you should add your code again!!! as it's not properly posted.

Comment: Did you really pack this up in a <Div> ? Where is your Document Header & Body? Maybe some browser will read this, but it is not HTML conform.

Comment: What exactly isn't working in the aspx page? Is is throwing an error?

Comment: We need to know what's _not_ working in order to be able to help you. If you can edit your question to be more specific, please flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

(1) Swap the order you include jQuery and jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

(2) Move the `<meta>` tag to `<head>`.